# Getting token works, but making payment not

Tags: paypal

I'm making a class to make a payment with paypal.

Getting a token via the function `getToken()` works and it spits out a good response (according to the documentation).

However, when I'm using that token to build up a payment with the same `sendAPICall()` used for the token; it only returns a empty string (according to var_dump() ).

If I copy the exact curl command from the api-information and paste the beare-token; it works. So something is wrong with my API call....

Clearly I'm missing something. Could anyone point me to the error?

The function which gets the Bearer-token:

```
public function getToken(){

    $headers = array(
        "Accept-Language" => 'en_US',   
        "Accept" => "application/json"
        );

    $t = json_decode($this->sendAPICall('grant_type=client_credentials', '/oauth2/token', $headers, true));
    if($t->error){
        $this->error = $t->error_description;
        $this->token = NULL;
        return false;
    }else{
        $this->token = $t; 
        return true;
    }

}
```

The function which should make the payment after checking there is a token available.

```
public function makePayment(){
    $this->getToken();

  if($this->error){
      return false;
  }else{

        $d = '{"intent":"sale",
                  "redirect_urls":{
                    "return_url":"'.$this->config['returnURL'].'",
                    "cancel_url":"'.$this->config['cancelURL'].'"
                  },
                  "payer":{
                    "payment_method":"paypal"
                  },
                  "transactions":[
                    {
                      "amount":{
                        "total":"'.$this->amount.'",
                        "currency":"'.$this->config['currency'].'"
                      },
                        "description":"'.$this->description.'"
                    }
                  ]
                }';
        $headers = array(   "Authorization" => $this->token->token_type . ' ' . $this->token->access_token, 
                            "Content-type" => "application/json"
                            );
        return $this->sendAPICall(urlencode($d), '/payments/payment', $headers, false);

    }
 }
```

And off course the connection with the paypal API, where I'm using the $auth boolean to make the difference between sending the userpwd or using the token:

```
private function sendAPICall($data, $url, $headers, $auth=true){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = array(   CURLOPT_URL => $this->config['endpoint'].$url,
                        CURLOPT_POST => true,
                        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true

                    );
        if($auth){
            $options[CURLOPT_USERPWD] = $this->config['client_id'].':'.$this->config['client_secret'];
        };
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    return curl_exec($ch);



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like this code snippet is passing HTTP headers correctly. CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER takes a unideimensional array with values of the form "headername: value". You need

$headers = array(
   "Authorization: " .  $this->token->token_type . ' ' . $this->token->access_token, 
   "Content-type: application/json"
);

Also consider

1. Checking for curl_errno($ch) / curl_error($ch) and the HTTP response code (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) to see if the call was successful.
2. Creating the request data as an associative array and using json_encode($data) when calling sendAPICall(). This is far easier than manipulating JSON strings manually.